# How does one document the returned data for a POST endpoint?

Tags: flask, swagger, flask-restplus

If I have a simple endpoint like so using flask

```
import random
class MyResource(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return [i for i in range (random.randrange(100))]
```

How do I get swagger documentation like so using flask-restplus?

[image]

I am looking for some data structure like so

```
[
    type=integer, description='coin flip',
    ....
]
```

I can get it to work for the Payload but not for the return/response

Comment: have you check this documentation ? https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html

Comment: @BenoîtZu I read that 100x but missed this line "You can optionally specify a response model as the third argument:". If you put as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html

> You can optionally specify a response model as the third argument

```
model = api.model('Model', {
    'name': fields.String,
})

@api.route('/my-resource/')
class MyResource(Resource):
    @api.response(200, 'Success', model)
    def get(self):
        pass
```